# Keep validations until corrected

Tags: jsf, primefaces

Our scenario is this - we have multiple text inputs on one screen, and have added a custom validator to filter which characters can be entered. The issue is, the client wants messages for all invalid fields to be shown, as well as highlighting the fields themselves. We're currently handling this by processing each of the field on the blur event of any of the individual fields. It works, but seems inefficient (and error prone, since we have to make sure the logic is adjusted if new fields are added. They don't share a parent container, and processing the entire form is not an option) - is there a better way to approach this?

Comment: What about a `<p:message>` tag for eacht text input? When validation fails, the error will be shown in the affected area.

Comment: The client wants a single container for all error messages. Also, this is a very large project, so such a large change would be prohibitively time consuming.